# custom Directive replace element not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a custom directive that generates an input with its validation errors , eventually after building the input, here is the part I'm wondering about :

```
var html= template.get();
 element.html(html);
 $compile(element)(scope);
```

I also added to the directive object which I think is not making difference since I don't have template in the object or should it?

```
replace:true
```

but yet the directive element DOM is still there , and the generated input is being appended as a child , can you help me out in this ?

Comment: please create a fiddle.

Comment: Or at the very least give us more of your code please

Comment: @MattWay http://jsfiddle.net/57nv846k/

Comment: @Chris http://jsfiddle.net/57nv846k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `replace` is used in conjunction with `template`/`templateUrl`.

For the templates that are retrieved dynamically in `link`, use

```
var html= template.get();
element.replaceWith($compile(html)(scope));
```

Notice that obvious drawback in comparison with `replace` is that directive's attributes won't be translated to template element, this has to be done manually.

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because you haven't provided a `template` parameter and your link function was manually adding the elements.  Remove the link function and add a template parameter like so and it'll work.  Ive updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57nv846k/1/) with it working too

```
app.directive('test',function($compile){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        replace:true,
        template:'<input type="text" name="test">'
    }
});
```

Comment: I have a complex logic to create the template , and I have some functions I need to call for initializing before creating the template , can it work in my link code without using the template ? I am already aware of this part as I mentioned in my question